# Corona SDK focus issue scrollview/buttons

Tags: button, scrollview, coronasdk

In a Corona SDK project I have a `scrollview` and, inside this scrollview, eight `buttons`.

Problem is when I scroll and at the same time I start scrolling from the position where a button is located, the button `touch event` fires and the scrollview doesn't scroll.

I tried to implement a `moved` listener on the scrollview but it didn't work. Is there any way to set the focus on the scrollview when it should scroll and on the button when there's a tap?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
local function scrollviewListener(event)
  if "moved" == event.phase then
    display.getCurrentStage():setFocus()
    scrollView:takeFocus( event )
  end  
 end

local scrollView = widget.newScrollView {
      top = screenTop + 220,
      left = screenLeft - 30,
      width = screenWidth + 30 ,
      height = screenHeight - 120,
      scrollWidth = screenWidth - 0.5,
      scrollHeight = screenHeight - 10,
      backgroundColor = {0.99, 0.99, 0.99},
      hideBackground = true,
      listener = scrollviewListener
    }
    group:insert(scrollView)
```